# gcc : reload pass and "reload_completed" in backend .md files

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compilation

I am working on a new backend to GCC and have been taking help from the existing machine description files for various targets.

Till now, I am not clear on the following :

1. What does the reload pass do ?
2. How does it interact with the combine pass ? I see lot of "reload_completed" check in the MIPS backend .md files. Why are some define_insn_and_split patterns with "reload_completed" vs others without ?

I have tried to read up on what the reload pass is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/reload), and also tried some searches on the gcc-help archive. Still, what the reload pass is, what it achieves, and its interaction with other passes like the combine pass is not clear to me. Can someone provide some more insight to this with examples ?